# Twitter API Status code 401 Could not Authenticate You Error {"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}

Tags: android, json, authentication, twitter

this is an app to get the trends in twitter.....im having trouble in authenticating...

the problem once i have authenticated into twitter using username and password and after redirecting back to my app i get the **status code 401** could not authenticate for the **GET request https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/available.json.**

I think the problem is in auth header for the get request

**{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}.**

Please help me out

Thanks in advance :)

**HERES MY AUTHENTICATION CLASS--AuthActivity.java**

```
package com.tmm.android.twitter;


import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.http.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.http.BASE64Encoder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tmm.android.twitter.appliaction.TwitterApplication;
import com.tmm.android.twitter.util.Constants;



public class AuthActivity extends Activity {

private Twitter twitter;
private OAuthProvider provider;
private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer;

private String CONSUMER_KEY =           Constants.CONSUMER_KEY;
private String CONSUMER_SECRET =        Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET;
private String CALLBACK_URL =           "https://www.google.co.in";

private Button buttonLogin;

SharedPreferences sharedPrefs=null;;
String verifiers=null;


String oauth_consumer_key="3pNHYDmpWsMGQry8V1Ohw";
String oauth_consumer_secret="YwB8KZNimt6tmBHqOMQFw75k3bEDaiw1WBcru3RRS8";

public static String oauth_nonce=null;

final String oauth_timestamp1=String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
final String oauth_timestamp=oauth_timestamp1.substring(0, 10);

public static String oauth_signature=null;
String oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1";  
public static String oauth_token; //access_token
String oauth_version="1.0";

public static String access_token_secret;
String secret;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_oauth);        


    //check for saved log in details..
    checkForSavedLogin();

    //set consumer and provider on teh Application service
    getConsumerProvider();

    //Define login button and listener
    buttonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonLogin);
    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("timestamp1",oauth_timestamp);
            askOAuth(); 


        }
    });
}




private void checkForSavedLogin() {
    // Get Access Token and persist it
    AccessToken a = getAccessToken();
    if (a==null) return;    //if there are no credentials stored then return to usual activity

    // initialize Twitter4J
    twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_SECRET, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
    ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).setTwitter(twitter);

    startFirstActivity();
    //finish();
}

/**
 * Kick off the activity to display 
 */
private void startFirstActivity() {
    System.out.println("STARTING FIRST ACTIVITY!");
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TweetsActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

/**
 * This method checks the shared prefs to see if we have persisted a user token/secret
 * if it has then it logs on using them, otherwise return null
 * 
 * @return AccessToken from persisted prefs
 */
private AccessToken getAccessToken() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String token = settings.getString("accessTokenToken", "");
    String tokenSecret = settings.getString("accessTokenSecret", "");
    if (token!=null && tokenSecret!=null && !"".equals(tokenSecret) && !"".equals(token)){
        return new AccessToken(token, tokenSecret);
    }
    return null;
}



/**
 * Open the browser and asks the user to authorize the app.
 * Afterwards, we redirect the user back here!
 */
private void askOAuth() {
    try {
        //          Log.e("timestamp",oauth_timestamp);
        //          Log.e("timestampbytes", oauth_timestamp.getBytes().toString());
        //          Log.e("nonce",oauth_nonce);

        Log.e("authUrl1", "hello");
        consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
        provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

        String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK_URL); //auth_token
        Log.e("authUrl", authUrl);

        String request_token=consumer.getToken();
        String request_token_secret=consumer.getTokenSecret();

        Log.d("request_token",request_token);
        Log.d("request_token_secret",request_token_secret);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please authorize this app!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setConsumerProvider();

        Intent web_i = new Intent (AuthActivity.this,Webview.class);
        web_i.putExtra("url", authUrl);
        startActivity(web_i);  


        //this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exception1", e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


/**
 * As soon as the user successfully authorized the app, we are notified
 * here. Now we need to get the verifier from the callback URL, retrieve
 * token and token_secret and feed them to twitter4j (as well as
 * consumer key and secret).
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("RESUMING!!");

    sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedprefs", 0);
        verifiers=sharedPrefs.getString("verifiers", "hello");
        Log.d("verifiers",verifiers);
        if(verifiers!="hello")
        {
        dealWithTwitterResponse();
        }

}


 public void dealWithTwitterResponse()
 {
     if(verifiers!=null)
     {

            try {
                // this will populate token and token_secret in consumer
                provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, verifiers);

                String accessss_token=consumer.getToken();
                String accessss_token_secret=consumer.getTokenSecret();

                oauth_token=accessss_token;

                access_token_secret=accessss_token_secret;
                Log.d("accessss_token",accessss_token);
                Log.d("accessss_token_secret",accessss_token_secret);


                // Get Access Token and persist it
                AccessToken a = new AccessToken(consumer.getToken(), consumer.getTokenSecret());

                Log.d("access_token", a.toString());
                storeAccessToken(a);

                // initialize Twitter4J
                twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

                twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
                ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).setTwitter(twitter);
                //Log.e("Login", "Twitter Initialised");


                String randomnum=random();
                oauth_nonce=randomnum+oauth_timestamp;

                Log.d("nonce",oauth_nonce);
                Log.d("timestamp2",oauth_timestamp);



                //  String signatureBaseString ="GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Ftrends%2Fplace.json&id%3D1%26oauth_consumer_key%3D"+oauth_consumer_key+"%26oauth_nonce%3D"+oauth_nonce+"%26oauth_signature_method%3D"+oauth_signature_method+"%26oauth_timestamp%3D"+oauth_timestamp+"%26oauth_token%3D"+oauth_token+"%26oauth_version%3D"+oauth_version;

                String signatureBaseString ="GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Ftrends%2Favailable.json&oauth_consumer_key%3D"+oauth_consumer_key+"%26oauth_nonce%3D"+oauth_nonce+"%26oauth_signature_method%3D"+oauth_signature_method+"%26oauth_timestamp%3D"+oauth_timestamp+"%26oauth_token%3D"+oauth_token+"%26oauth_version%3D"+oauth_version;

                Log.d("signatureBaseString", signatureBaseString);

                secret=oauth_consumer_secret+"&"+access_token_secret;

                Log.d("secrets", secret);

                String toHash = URLEncoder.encode(signatureBaseString);
                String hash;
                try {
                    hash = computeHmac(toHash, secret);
                    oauth_signature=hash;
                    Log.d("signature", oauth_signature);                            

                    String sign=URLEncoder.encode(oauth_signature);
                    Log.d("sign", sign);

                    oauth_signature=sign;




                } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                startFirstActivity();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Log.e(APP, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("exception2", e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
     //     }
    else
    {
        Log.e("error","error");
    }
}
 // }


/**
 * This method persists the Access Token information so that a user
 * is not required to re-login every time the app is used
 * 
 * @param a - the access token
 */
private void storeAccessToken(AccessToken a) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    Log.d("a.token",a.getToken());
    Log.d("a.token_secret",a.getTokenSecret());

    editor.putString("accessTokenToken", a.getToken());
    editor.putString("accessTokenSecret", a.getTokenSecret());
    editor.commit();
}


/**
 * Get the consumer and provider from the application service (in the case that the
 * activity is restarted so the objects are not lost
 */
private void getConsumerProvider() {
    OAuthProvider p = ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).getProvider();
    if (p!=null){
        provider = p;
    }
    CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer c = ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).getConsumer();
    if (c!=null){
        consumer = c;
    }
}


/**
 * Set the consumer and provider from the application service (in the case that the
 * activity is restarted so the objects are not lost)
 */
private void setConsumerProvider() {
    if (provider!=null){
        ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).setProvider(provider);
    }
    if (consumer!=null){
        ((TwitterApplication)getApplication()).setConsumer(consumer);
    }
}


public String random()
{
    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
        char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
        sb.append(c);
    }
    String output = sb.toString();
    //System.out.println(output);
    return output;
}

public String computeHmac(String baseString, String key) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), mac.getAlgorithm());
    mac.init(secret);
    byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes());

    return new String(BASE64Encoder.encode(digest));
}
```

}

**HERES MY TWEETS ACTIVITY CLASS  TweetsActivity.java**

```
package com.tmm.android.twitter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class TweetsActivity extends Activity {

//AuthActivity aa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //aa=new AuthActivity(); 

    String TAG_NAME="name";


    //      String url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json";

    String url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/available.json";


    Log.e("json url2",url);
    JSONParser jparser=new JSONParser();
    JSONArray json= jparser.getJSONfromURL(url);


    }


**}
```

HERES MY JSON PARSER CLASS --JSONParser.java**

```
package com.tmm.android.twitter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {


JSONArray jarray;

AuthActivity aa;

public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONArray getJSONfromURL(String url)
{
    aa=new AuthActivity(); 

    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient httpclient =new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget=new HttpGet(url);
//      HttpParams params=new BasicHttpParams();
//      params.setParameter("id", "1");

    String hurl= "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\""+aa.oauth_consumer_key+"\", oauth_nonce=\""+aa.oauth_nonce+"\", oauth_signature=\""+aa.oauth_signature+"\", oauth_signature_method=\""+aa.oauth_signature_method+"\", oauth_timestamp=\""+aa.oauth_timestamp+"\", oauth_token=\""+aa.oauth_token+"\", oauth_version=\""+aa.oauth_version+"\"";


    httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");       
    httpget.setHeader("Authorization",hurl);
 //     httpget.setParams(params);

    Log.d("oathheaders",hurl);

    try
    {
        HttpResponse httpresponse= httpclient.execute(httpget); 

        StatusLine statusLine= httpresponse.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode= statusLine.getStatusCode();

        Log.d("status code",String.valueOf(statusCode));
        //          if(statusCode==200)
        //          {
            HttpEntity httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();

            InputStream content= httpentity.getContent();


            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;

            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                sb.append(line);                    
            }

            System.out.println(sb.toString());

//          }
//          else
//          {
//              Log.e("error", "FAILED TO DOWNLOAD FILE");
//          }
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   


    try
    {
        jarray= new JSONArray(sb.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e1) 
    {
        Log.e("parseerror", "Error parsing data "+e1.toString());
    }
    return jarray;

    }

}
```

HERES MY LOGCAT SHOWING ERRORS AND Log.d Values

```
03-27 17:00:26.533: D/dalvikvm(13599): Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-27 17:00:27.638: I/System.out(13599): RESUMING!!
03-27 17:00:27.638: D/verifiers(13599): hello
03-27 17:00:29.288: D/GestureDetector(13599): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
03-27 17:00:29.353: D/timestamp1(13599): 1395919827
03-27 17:00:29.353: E/authUrl1(13599): hello
03-27 17:00:32.708: D/dalvikvm(13599): GC_CONCURRENT freed 290K, 8% free 12286K/13319K, paused 113ms+17ms, total 210ms
03-27 17:00:33.813: E/authUrl(13599): https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=LyX3bXZifIBKgh0c5n0PHb8YVUB6Tp1JEd2wziDT4l8
03-27 17:00:33.813: D/request_token(13599): LyX3bXZifIBKgh0c5n0PHb8YVUB6Tp1JEd2wziDT4l8
03-27 17:00:33.813: D/request_token_secret(13599): dZTuoka9tkdZmaHXqcs9v3hHksh2EQ89wWh6uX6o
03-27 17:00:34.928: I/webclipboard(13599): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41de1618
03-27 17:00:35.148: D/authorization url(13599): https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=LyX3bXZifIBKgh0c5n0PHb8YVUB6Tp1JEd2wziDT4l8
03-27 17:00:35.173: D/WebView(13599): loadUrlImpl: called
03-27 17:00:35.183: D/dalvikvm(13599): GC_CONCURRENT freed 327K, 9% free 12418K/13511K, paused 14ms+19ms, total 80ms
03-27 17:00:35.253: I/Choreographer(13599): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 17:00:35.293: E/webview(13599): registerForStylusPenEvent onAttachedToWindow
03-27 17:00:35.293: E/webview(13599): registerForStylusPenEvent START
03-27 17:00:35.303: E/webview(13599): registerForStylusPenEvent END
03-27 17:00:35.358: D/WebView(13599): onSizeChanged - w:320 h:467
03-27 17:00:35.633: E/SpannableStringBuilder(13599): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-27 17:00:35.643: E/SpannableStringBuilder(13599): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-27 17:00:35.768: V/webkit(13599): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {41ddb2b0}
03-27 17:00:35.858: D/webcore(13599):  CORE loadUrl: called
03-27 17:00:35.858: D/webkit(13599): Firewall not null
03-27 17:00:35.863: D/webkit(13599): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
03-27 17:00:38.273: I/System.out(13599): RESUMING!!
03-27 17:00:38.278: D/verifiers(13599): hello
03-27 17:00:38.343: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13599): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-27 17:00:38.343: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13599): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
03-27 17:00:38.418: E/webview(13599): removeForStylusPenEvent onDetachedFromWindow
03-27 17:00:38.418: E/webview(13599): removeForStylusPenEvent START
03-27 17:00:38.418: E/webview(13599): removeForStylusPenEvent END
03-27 17:00:44.448: I/GATE(13599): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
03-27 17:00:50.858: D/GestureDetector(13599): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
03-27 17:00:50.863: D/timestamp1(13599): 1395919827
03-27 17:00:50.863: E/authUrl1(13599): hello
03-27 17:00:52.833: D/dalvikvm(13599): GC_CONCURRENT freed 395K, 9% free 12461K/13639K, paused 24ms+10ms, total 142ms
03-27 17:00:53.728: E/authUrl(13599): https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=JisvmQahwUKUPqM1YTF9GE7aWtE7jIXxAsHsUmyJR5I
03-27 17:00:53.728: D/request_token(13599): JisvmQahwUKUPqM1YTF9GE7aWtE7jIXxAsHsUmyJR5I
03-27 17:00:53.733: D/request_token_secret(13599): 9B5DvKITcjv1elvCE0jF1BpOHgkFFY8Rk3eXUDV0g
03-27 17:00:54.063: V/webkit(13599): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {41e0db88}
03-27 17:00:54.068: I/webclipboard(13599): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41e0b6b0
03-27 17:00:54.083: D/authorization url(13599): https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=JisvmQahwUKUPqM1YTF9GE7aWtE7jIXxAsHsUmyJR5I
03-27 17:00:54.088: D/WebView(13599): loadUrlImpl: called
03-27 17:00:54.088: D/webcore(13599):  CORE loadUrl: called
03-27 17:00:54.093: D/webkit(13599): Firewall not null
03-27 17:00:54.093: D/webkit(13599): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
03-27 17:00:54.108: E/webview(13599): registerForStylusPenEvent onAttachedToWindow
03-27 17:00:54.108: E/webview(13599): registerForStylusPenEvent START
03-27 17:00:54.108: E/webview(13599): registerForStylusPenEvent END
03-27 17:00:54.133: D/WebView(13599): onSizeChanged - w:320 h:467
03-27 17:00:54.203: E/SpannableStringBuilder(13599): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-27 17:00:54.203: E/SpannableStringBuilder(13599): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-27 17:00:56.538: D/GestureDetector(13599): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 5 mFalseSizeCnt:0
03-27 17:00:56.538: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(13599): blockWebkitDraw
03-27 17:00:56.538: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(13599): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
03-27 17:00:56.543: V/webview(13599):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
03-27 17:00:56.843: D/webview(13599): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
03-27 17:00:57.668: I/GATE(13599): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
03-27 17:00:59.163: D/GestureDetector(13599): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 4 mFalseSizeCnt:0
03-27 17:00:59.163: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(13599): blockWebkitDraw
03-27 17:00:59.163: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(13599): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
03-27 17:00:59.168: V/webview(13599):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
03-27 17:00:59.468: D/webview(13599): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
03-27 17:00:59.568: D/webcoreglue(13599): WebViewCore::nextTextOrSelectNode : Broken after finding a focusable Node
03-27 17:00:59.568: D/webcoreglue(13599): WebViewCore::nextTextOrSelectNode : Final Next Nodename = <INPUT>, tagname = <INPUT>
03-27 17:00:59.568: D/webcoreglue(13599): WebViewCore::previousTextOrSelectNode :  !previousNode )
03-27 17:00:59.948: D/WebView(13599): onSizeChanged - w:320 h:219
03-27 17:01:38.863: D/dalvikvm(13599): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 183K, 9% free 12590K/13831K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
03-27 17:01:39.348: D/GestureDetector(13599): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 19 mFalseSizeCnt:0
03-27 17:01:39.348: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(13599): blockWebkitDraw
03-27 17:01:39.348: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(13599): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
03-27 17:01:39.348: V/webview(13599):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
03-27 17:01:39.913: D/GestureDetector(13599): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
03-27 17:01:39.913: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(13599): blockWebkitDraw
03-27 17:01:39.913: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(13599): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
03-27 17:01:39.913: V/webview(13599):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
03-27 17:01:40.213: D/webview(13599): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
03-27 17:01:40.243: D/webcoreglue(13599): WebViewCore::nextTextOrSelectNode :  nextNode is NULL
03-27 17:01:40.308: D/webcoreglue(13599): WebViewCore::previousTextOrSelectNode : Broken after finding a focusable Node
03-27 17:01:40.308: D/webcoreglue(13599): WebViewCore::previousTextOrSelectNode : Final Previous Nodename = <INPUT>, tagname = <INPUT>
03-27 17:01:40.433: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13599): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-27 17:01:40.558: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13599): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-27 17:01:41.078: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13599): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-27 17:01:58.828: D/GestureDetector(13599): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 14 mFalseSizeCnt:0
03-27 17:01:58.828: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(13599): blockWebkitDraw
03-27 17:01:58.828: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(13599): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
03-27 17:01:58.828: V/webview(13599):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
03-27 17:01:59.268: D/GestureDetector(13599): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
03-27 17:01:59.268: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(13599): blockWebkitDraw
03-27 17:01:59.268: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(13599): blockWebkitDraw lockedfalse
03-27 17:01:59.268: V/webview(13599):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
03-27 17:01:59.573: D/webview(13599): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
03-27 17:01:59.823: D/dalvikvm(13599): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 219K, 9% free 12655K/13831K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
03-27 17:01:59.823: I/dalvikvm-heap(13599): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.331MB for 279056-byte allocation
03-27 17:01:59.848: D/dalvikvm(13599): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13K, 9% free 12914K/14151K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
03-27 17:01:59.913: D/WebView(13599): onSizeChanged - w:320 h:467
03-27 17:02:06.438: D/GestureDetector(13599): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
03-27 17:02:11.563: I/GATE(13599): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
03-27 17:02:11.593: D/client 1(13599): https://www.google.co.in/?oauth_token=JisvmQahwUKUPqM1YTF9GE7aWtE7jIXxAsHsUmyJR5I&oauth_verifier=mh9kppYyCpqKKQJvNzvQJq7Jfpc6f2rZHWCryMAzCU
03-27 17:02:11.598: D/WebView(13599): loadUrlImpl: called
03-27 17:02:11.598: D/client 2(13599): client2
03-27 17:02:11.618: D/veri(13599): mh9kppYyCpqKKQJvNzvQJq7Jfpc6f2rZHWCryMAzCU
03-27 17:02:11.663: D/WebCore(13599): uiOverrideUrlLoading: shouldOverrideUrlLoading() returnstrue
03-27 17:02:11.668: D/webcore(13599):  CORE loadUrl: called
03-27 17:02:11.668: D/webkit(13599): Firewall not null
03-27 17:02:11.668: D/webkit(13599): euler: isUrlBlocked = false
03-27 17:02:11.713: I/System.out(13599): RESUMING!!
03-27 17:02:11.713: D/verifiers(13599): mh9kppYyCpqKKQJvNzvQJq7Jfpc6f2rZHWCryMAzCU
03-27 17:02:12.153: D/dalvikvm(13599): GC_CONCURRENT freed 544K, 10% free 12810K/14151K, paused 12ms+5ms, total 38ms
03-27 17:02:14.423: D/accessss_token(13599): 100169976-iH3DymZLLlVXyXm3VaY48BnBRfzfDjRmqsWbuaOR
03-27 17:02:14.423: D/accessss_token_secret(13599): JfBbgSoefa1iNqCC0Yh7yQkpMwvBTQPVIFXUoxP6Qs6Ne
03-27 17:02:14.428: D/access_token(13599): AccessToken{screenName='null', userId=0}
03-27 17:02:14.428: D/a.token(13599): 100169976-iH3DymZLLlVXyXm3VaY48BnBRfzfDjRmqsWbuaOR
03-27 17:02:14.428: D/a.token_secret(13599): JfBbgSoefa1iNqCC0Yh7yQkpMwvBTQPVIFXUoxP6Qs6Ne
03-27 17:02:14.488: D/nonce(13599): gsrtrvq124n36raqmf2mdi1395919827
03-27 17:02:14.488: D/timestamp2(13599): 1395919827
03-27 17:02:14.488: D/signatureBaseString(13599): GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Ftrends%2Favailable.json&oauth_consumer_key%3D3pNHYDmpWsMGQry8V1Ohw%26oauth_nonce%3Dgsrtrvq124n36raqmf2mdi1395919827%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1395919827%26oauth_token%3D100169976-iH3DymZLLlVXyXm3VaY48BnBRfzfDjRmqsWbuaOR%26oauth_version%3D1.0
03-27 17:02:14.488: D/secrets(13599): YwB8KZNimt6tmBHqOMQFw75k3bEDaiw1WBcru3RRS8&JfBbgSoefa1iNqCC0Yh7yQkpMwvBTQPVIFXUoxP6Qs6Ne
03-27 17:02:14.498: D/signature(13599): sp6n3AagNKYFpno7XfU/zZ2zmck=
03-27 17:02:14.498: D/sign(13599): sp6n3AagNKYFpno7XfU%2FzZ2zmck%3D
03-27 17:02:14.498: I/System.out(13599): STARTING FIRST ACTIVITY!
03-27 17:02:14.508: D/dalvikvm(13599): GC_CONCURRENT freed 508K, 11% free 12710K/14151K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 39ms
03-27 17:02:14.513: I/Choreographer(13599): Skipped 158 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-27 17:02:14.653: E/json url2(13599): https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/available.json
03-27 17:02:14.658: D/oathheaders(13599): OAuth oauth_consumer_key="3pNHYDmpWsMGQry8V1Ohw", oauth_nonce="gsrtrvq124n36raqmf2mdi1395919827", oauth_signature="sp6n3AagNKYFpno7XfU%2FzZ2zmck%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1395919934", oauth_token="100169976-iH3DymZLLlVXyXm3VaY48BnBRfzfDjRmqsWbuaOR", oauth_version="1.0"
03-27 17:02:15.398: I/GATE(13599): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
03-27 17:02:17.133: D/dalvikvm(13599): GC_CONCURRENT freed 305K, 10% free 12799K/14151K, paused 9ms+10ms, total 82ms
03-27 17:02:17.598: W/DefaultRequestDirector(13599): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
03-27 17:02:17.598: D/status code(13599): 401
03-27 17:02:17.603: I/System.out(13599): {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}
03-27 17:02:17.613: E/parseerror(13599): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
03-27 17:02:17.628: I/Choreographer(13599): Skipped 170 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/documentation

> Please verify that the time of your machine is correctly setup (both
>   the time and the region). Having an incorrect Time can result in
>   receiving the 401 exception.

If this is not the case then following links which might be helpful:

[Why is my call to get Twitter user timeline returning "401 Unauthorized."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217664/why-is-my-call-to-get-twitter-user-timeline-returning-401-unauthorized?rq=1)

[401 error while trying to call Twitter stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287899/401-error-while-trying-to-call-twitter-stream-api?rq=1)

[Twitter API Integration - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834318/twitter-api-integration-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorize?rq=1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.